# Why doesn't a css transition fire immediately after display change

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

**TL;DR** A css transition on **opacity** does not work immediately after **display** change, but works with `setTimeout(.., 100)`. Why?

## What do I want?

I want to flash a message for a couple of seconds and then fade it out. Seems pretty basic, right?

## What do I have?

Well, here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pswh7db/9/), but let me explain in detail.

Say I have a message block

```
<div id="message" class="message">
  Here be dragons
</div>
```

Which starts hidden but opaque

```
.message {
  opacity: 1;      
  display: none;
}
```

Once I've prepared my message I want to show it.

```
document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block"
```

Now I want the message to fade out so I added a simple transition on opacity.

```
.flash {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out 1s;
}
```

Which I apply with the following

```
document.getElementById("message").classList.add("flash")
```

## What goes wrong?

The message div is shown but it stays invisible as the `opacity: 0` immediately applies. Besides, the `transitionend` event is not firing, which makes me think the transition *does not happen at all* for some reason. Weird, right?

However, everything's fine once I add the timeout

```
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block"
  setTimeout(() => (document.getElementById("message").classList.add("flash")), 100)
```

That works but seems like a totally dirty hack. Why is it like this?

You can see this behaviour on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pswh7db/9/) with two buttons aptly named 'Working' and 'Not working';

Comment: "here's a jsfiddle, but let me explain in detail." To avoid future problems, and to be clear, if you only put your code in a jsfiddle, that will get your question closed. [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that together cause this:

- When items have `display: none` the `opacity` is ignored (as not relevant). And so when you apply `display: block` to them they render the provided `opacity` with the *current* value without any transition effect.
- Changes you apply to the `style` attribute all apply together at the moment a paint (asynchronous) happens, and so the `transition` definition comes too late.

First, make sure to set the transition effect definition before the actual application of it, in the `message` CSS class.

I would then suggest using `height` instead of `display` to get the same effect. You would need to switch the border on and off also (through its width):

```js
document.getElementById("working").addEventListener("click" , () => {
  document.getElementById("message").classList.add("flash");
})

// reset
document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("transitionend" , () => {
  document.getElementById("message").classList.remove("flash")
})
```

```css
.message {
  border: solid 0px;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.flash {
  height: 100%; 
  opacity: 0;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<div id="message" class="message">
  Here be dragons
</div>

<button id="working"> Working </button>
```

Comment: "Changes you apply to the style attribute all apply together at the moment a paint (asynchronous) happens", This! This is exactly an example of basics that everyone _should_ know! It all makes sense now.

And thanks for the tip on `height`!

Answer (score 1):

Why it doesn't work is because you are applying `display:block` and `opactiy: 0` at the same time. When you set the attribute `display` in css it ignores all transition, there has to be an event in between setting display and transitions. An alternative is using `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead of display but note that this only hides the element and the element is still present in its position